# More general or efficient approach for this matrix multiplication?

Tags: r, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

In R, is there a more efficient and/or general way to produce the desired output from the two matrices below? I'm suspicious that what I've done is just some esoteric matrix multiplication operation of which I'm not aware.

```
ff <- matrix(1:6,ncol=2)
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    4
# [2,]    2    5
# [3,]    3    6

bb <- matrix(7:10,ncol=2)
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    7    9
# [2,]    8   10

# DESIRE:
#  7 36
# 14 45
# 21 54
#  8 40
# 16 50
# 24 60
```

This works, but isn't the general solution I'm looking for:

```
rr1 <- t(t(ff) * bb[1,])
rr2 <- t(t(ff) * bb[2,])
rbind(rr1,rr2)
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    7   36
# [2,]   14   45
# [3,]   21   54
# [4,]    8   40
# [5,]   16   50
# [6,]   24   60
```

This next code block seems pretty efficient and is general. But is there a better way?
Something like `kronecker(ffa,bba)`? (which clearly doesn't work in this case)

```
ffa <- matrix(rep(t(ff),2), ncol=2, byrow=T)
bba <- matrix(rep(bb,each=3), ncol=2)
ffa * bba
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    7   36
# [2,]   14   45
# [3,]   21   54
# [4,]    8   40
# [5,]   16   50
# [6,]   24   60
```

This is related to my other questions:

1. [Using apply function over the row margin with expectation of stacked results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54538730/using-apply-function-over-the-row-margin-with-expectation-of-stacked-results), where I'm trying to understand the behavior of `apply` itself and:
2. [Is this an example of some more general matrix product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101372/is-this-an-example-of-some-more-general-matrix-product), where I'm asking about the theoretical math, specifically.

Comment: Isn't this similar post you have posted earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54538730/using-apply-function-over-the-row-margin-with-expectation-of-stacked-results)

Comment: Earlier, I wanted to know specifically what was happening with the `apply` function with regards to this particular problem. Here, I'd like to know if there's a more general/efficient approach, to get the desired output, without using `apply`, necessarily.

Comment: Perhaps you need `do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(nrow(bb)),  function(i) t(t(ff) * bb[i, ])))`

Comment: Are you looking for *computational* efficiency? On matrices of what size? Different solutions may be fastest for small matrices like in this example compared to large matrices.

Comment: My actual use case is for `ff` 45x16 and `bb` 1620x16. Speed is most important. I found that Grothendieck's `mapply` solution was fastest in this case. Haven't benchmarked the `KhatriRao` method though.

Comment: For those interested, I microbenchmarked on my actual data: 1. my solution (in the original question), 2. Grothendieck's `kronecker` solution, 3. Grothendieck's `mapply` solution, and 4. Langsrud's `KhatriRao` solution. I found median runtimes of 36, 200, 20, 314 (in nanoseconds, for 10 runs each). So, `mapply` is the speed winner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a kronecker product and pick off the appropriate columns:

```
kronecker(bb, ff)[, c(diag(ncol(bb))) == 1]
```

or using the infix operator for kronecker:

```
(bb %x% ff)[, c(diag(ncol(bb))) == 1]
```

Another approach is to convert the arguments to data frames and `mapply` `kronecker` across them.  For the case in the question this performs the calculation `cbind(bb[, 1] %x% ff[, 1], bb[, 2] %x% ff[, 2])` but in a more general manner without resorting to indices:

```
mapply(kronecker, as.data.frame(bb), as.data.frame(ff))
```

or using the infix operator for `kronecker`:

```
mapply(`%x%`, as.data.frame(bb), as.data.frame(ff))
```

Comment: I ended up using your `mapply` solution because it was the fastest, easily interpretable, and didn't require loading of an additional package. Close call between this and Langsrud's `KhatriRao` solution

Answer (score 3):

The functionality you are seeking for is available within the Matrix package as the function KhatriRao. Since the function is in Matrix, output is a matrix of class "dgCMatrix" (sparse matrix). You can transform it to an ordinary matrix of class "matrix" by as.matrix.

```
library(Matrix)
as.matrix(KhatriRao(bb, ff))
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22126695)